# How can I 301 redirect from university domain subfolder to new domain

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, redirection

My webpage on the university domain was located at:

```
www.example.edu/~myusername
```

I only have the index.html inside my `public_html` directory in my home area on the linux server.

I want to redirect homepage (which is the only page I have) to a new domain

```
www.example.com
```

I have tried to redirect the old `index.html` to the new `index.html` using 301 redirect and the standard methods found online using the `.htaccess` file, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* your university webserver uses Apache httpd, the most robust method is to place a `.htaccess` file within the document root:

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/
```

This will also redirect subpaths correctly.

---

Failing that, the second-best way is to use a scripting language (if you have access to one) to send a redierct header. This can be a PHP script, or a CGI script (placed in cgi-bin).

---

If all else fails, you can place a [meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) within your HTML file. This is the worst method, as it requires the browser to load the HTML page and then load the page it redirects to, while the redirect headers don't require loading the body. A meta refresh cannot be used to send a 301 redirect (which is necessarily an HTTP header).

Comment: Just to clarify - this is the folder structure that I have
 
`/home/myusername/public_html`

And my website address is www.univ.edu/~myusername. 

I placed a .htaccess file inside the aforementioned public_html folder with the following content.


`RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/`

However, I get a 500 internal server error when I do this.

Comment: You should not need `RewriteEngine` as `Redirect` is provided by `mod_alias`. Also try playing with paths like redirecting from `/~username/`. And try quoting the paths.

Comment: Thank you @Bob. Turns out removing the first two lines and simply putting `Redirect 301 /~username http://www.example.com` worked.